# Select Element Array and Then Give it Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 6 element and i want to select the 5th element (with jQuery)

```
$(".deskripsi")[2]
```

then give it a method, but when i try it it give me error in console log

```
$(".deskripsi")[2].innerHTML is not a function
```

can somebody tell my how to select element array in jQuery and give it method.

oke, may it's seems my question is still unclear. my point is to select that element (array number 5), innerHTML is just only for to see in my console log if i select the right target.

please let me give another example.
let say i have 6 list like this

```
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
<li>D</li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
</ul>
```

now i want to select the li number 5
(i use innerHTML only for check the li value)

Thanks

Comment: Please post more code if none of the current answers solve your problem.

Comment: *innerHTML* isn't a function - it's a property.  You set it using the assignment operator, e.g. `$(".deskripsi")[2].innerHTML = '<b>Test</b>';`.  jQuery's *.html()* function maps to this property, so the answers here should help get you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`:eq(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$(".deskripsi:eq(2)").html();
```

Comment: the answer is pretty simple :), but is really right.. thank you IT's work now :D

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to write

```
 $(".deskripsi")[2].innerHTML()
```

instead, use

```
 $(".deskripsi")[2].innerHTML
```

or

```
 $(".deskripsi").eq(2).html()
```

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$(".deskripsi").eq(2)
```

The [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method returns a wrapped jQuery set with one element, hence you can still invoke jQuery operations. This is not the case with `[2]` where you get the raw DOM element.

On the jQuery wrapped "set" (of one element) you can then use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function:

```
$('.deskripsi').eq(2).html(); // Retruns the HTML of the element
```

Answer (score 0):

If your browser supports CSS3, you may do:

```
$(".deskripsi:nth-child(5)").something();
```

Otherwise you must ensure that jQuery selector returns multiple entries - assign results to variable and access one of them. As my predecessors said - you can also use "eq()" function. ;]

Comment: jQuery uses its own selector engine and makes smart decisions about when to use the browser's.  *:nth-child()* will work in any browser that jQuery supports.

Comment: The point of `:nth-child()` (http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) in jQuery is to be independent of CSS3 support, I guess.

Comment: this night, i will test the code you give me. hope this will work. thx

Comment: @Andy E, I wouldn't say jQuery uses any "smart" decisions. See this: http://dhtmlkitchen.com/?category=/JavaScript/&date=2010/09/09/&entry=JavaScript-Query-Engines

Comment: @J-P: funny you should mention that, I intended to remove the word "smart" and leave decisions to make the comment a little less subjective, but I probably got distracted.  By "smart" I meant that when parsing a selector, jQuery/Sizzle *might* decide to use the native implementation of *querySelectorAll()*, if available.

Comment: @Tomasz: The reason I didn't up vote your answer wasn't because I didn't like it, it was because we don't have any idea of what the HTML markup looks like.  *:nth-child()*, will select elements that are the nth child of their parent. If each *.deskripsi* element has a different parent element your selector will not work.  *:eq()* is more suitable in this situation.